# MySql 'min' in 'WHERE' clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have this query

```
select date(fecha) as day, min(num) as mi  
from myTable 
where date(fecha) >= date(now()) 
group by day;
```

how I can add this condition in where `mi < 10` similar to

```
select date(fecha) as day, min(num) as mi  
from myTable 
where date(fecha) >= date(now()) 
and mi < 10 
group by day;
```

Comment: using having in your query should solve the problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use a "having" statement

```
select date(fecha) as day, min(num) as mi  
from myTable where date(fecha) >= date(now()) 
group by day
having min(num) < 10;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this query has all kinds of fun performance implications (aimed mostly at Juan, just this commented seemed to fit more here than on the question).  Namely, date(fecha) >= date(now()) requires a full table scan (whereas precalculating today's date would remedy that). Also, a HAVING clause requires a full scan of the results of a query involving a group by (similar to a full table scan, but likely completely in memory).  That one is a bit more difficult to alleviate though.

Comment: Agreed.  The date(fecha) is the problem, not the date(now()) though I believe.  However, since the date(fecha) is also in the select statement, the full table scan is required already, so the where clause doesn't really hurt anything more.  As Corbin said, a precalculated date would be best for performance here.

Comment: Well you could actually get rid of the date(fetcha).  For example, assume today is 2012-03-07.  Assume fecha is some datetime.  For all date(fecha) >= today, fecha >= today.  (Because date(column) is always >= column.)  So, the entire clause could be done with an index (guess I should've explicitly mentioned that...)

Comment: yes, very true.  The problem is the need to select and group by the date (without the time)

Comment: Ah true, I completely forgot about that part.  Though hopefully the recordset would have been whittled down significantly by that point.  In other words, the WHERE clause applies to the entire table, and the GROUP BY clause only applies to the set left after the WHERE clause. So, could potentially still be a performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this...

```
select date(fecha) as day, min(num) as mi  
from myTable 
where date(fecha) >= date(now()) 
and num < 10 
group by day;
```